# Displaying nested values in UITableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have 4 Strings like str1 = "user/doc/app/ios/simulator", str2= "user/file/app/ios/simulator",str3= "user2/doc/app/ios/simulator",str4="user/doc/app/ios/simulator". Now I want to decompose these strings and display it in table view. Like first I should get user and user2. If i tap on user I should get file,doc. How can I Achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 NSArray *stringComponents = [str1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"//"];
```

Your array will now contain each part of the string so you can chose the bits you want.

Comment: For individual string we can do it. But requirement is like we need to do for all the strings and get the desired output